# Ionic3 - API and syncing friends list when data is updated

Tags: api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a Ionic3 app using an API.
This API provides a friends list. This is working and I get a list of friends when I enter that view.

But when I am still in that view with the friends list, how can I update that list if a other user removes me from his / her friends list, so that we are basically not friends anymore. I could do some polling every X seconds to update the list, but is there a better way ?

Comment: You can re run listing array when friend list page open.

Comment: @DevangMistry: Do you mean polling the API for every X seconds ?

Comment: no , you can re run your listing code on page load event.
 example :
ionViewDidLoad(){
 call your listing function here;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use sockets,you need your API to let some device know that someone deleted them, there is some great documentation on Socket.IO. I had a similar issue, so I made a simple NodeJS server with a basic implementation of sockets and then implemented sockets on Ionic.

First: Install Socket.IO in your Ionic project: `npm install ng-socket-io --save`

Then add these three lines to your `app.module.ts`

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ng-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3001', options: {} };

@NgModule({
   /.../
 imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
     SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
 ],
  /.../
})
```

Finally on your `friends-list.ts`

```
import { Socket } from 'ng-socket-io'
export class FriendListPage { 
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private socket: Socket) {
          this.socket.connect();
    }

    deleteFriend(friend) {
        // Friend deletion logic
        this.socket.emit('delete-friend', friend);
    }

    onFriendDeletion() {
        let observable = new Observable(observer => {
            this.socket.on('deletion', (data) => {
                observer.next(data);
            });
        })
        return observable;
    }

    refreshOnDelete() {
        this.onFriendDeletion().subscribe(data => {
            //Refresh friend list.
        });
    }
}
```

This is a really basic example of what you need to do on the Ionic side. There's a great tutorial on [Devdactic](https://devdactic.com/ionic-realtime-socket-io/), it teaches you how to make a chat app with a basic NodeJS server and Ionic, but you change it up a bit for it to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this will get me started :)